# How to check if a boolean search is valid

Tags: php, mysql, validation

Long story short, I have a reporting system that allows users to enter a custom logic.

For example their logic might be `1 AND (2 OR 3) AND 4`.

Each of the numbers in the logic represent a filter criteria. If the filter criteria matches, it replaces the number with `true`, if not it replaces the number with `false`.

I wanted to find a way to validate if the logic above matches the criteria. So I created the following code and used MySQL to check it:

```
// The filter criteria... 
$filters = array(
    '1' => true,
    '2' => false,
    '3' => true,
    '4' => true
);

// The users custom logic
$logic = '1 AND (2 OR 3) AND 4';

// Put brackets around each number so that 10 doesn't conflict with 1
$logic = preg_replace("/([0-9]+)/", "[\\1]", $logic);

// $logic now looks like: [1] AND ([2] OR [3]) AND [4]

// Go through each filter and replace the relevant number
foreach($filters AS $filter_id => $filter_bool) {
    $logic = str_replace('[' . $filter_id . ']', $filter_bool, $logic);
}

// $logic now looks like: true AND (false OR true) AND true

// Check the query logic using MySQL
$match = $mysql->get_row("SELECT (" . $logic . ") AS result");

// Result
if ($match->result == 1)
    echo 'Filters match!';
else
    echo 'Failed!';
```

My question is, is there a way for my to validate the logic without using MySQL? If I have 10,000 records to validate, it has to make 10,000 MySQL calls to check each one.

Hopefully I am making sense :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: [EVAL()](http://www.php.net/eval)?

Comment: The computer scientifically correct way would be to write a small specialised parser that evaluates this expression in PHP; that's not entirely trivial though if you've never done this. The pragmatic solution would be to `eval` the string in PHP, but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: `eval` was the answer. Thank you both! I've posted my code below. I've just put it into production it cuts the time to load a page in half. It's ugly but it's fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @valex and @deceze I ended up using [eval](http://www.php.net/eval).

I did a test loop which I ran 1,000,000 times (a bit excessive maybe) to see which was the faster and `eval` had an average of 13 seconds where MYSQL had an average of 92 seconds. Wow! Massive difference.

My `eval` code:

```
$query = 'true AND (false OR true) AND true';
eval("if (" . $query . ") \$valid = 1; else \$valid = 0;");
if ($valid === 1)
    echo 'Match!';
else
    echo 'Failed!';
```

One thing I must warn people is about the message from PHP's documentation regarding the use of `eval`.

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Make sure any user inputted code is cleaned and validated before use within `eval`.

This will have to do for now but I hope to find a better solution in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have php 5.3 you can try to use http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/introduction.html#usage

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your `$logic` to this

> SELECT * FROM `booltest` WHERE `1` = 1 AND (`2` = 1 OR  `3` = 1) AND
>   `4` = 1

Using this table with tinyint(1) for [**BOOL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) where 1==true 0 ==false

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booltest` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
  );
```

And test table

```
INSERT INTO `booltest` (`id`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
(2, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(3, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(4, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(5, 0, 1, 0, 0),
(6, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

See [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0090c1/3)

Comment: Thanks David but I think you might have misunderstood my question. I am using MySQL (my code I used above works) but I would like to move away from it.